# Recursive setTimeout maxing out CPU in v8

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, v8

I have a recursive function that periodically checks a predicate and, if true, executes a function passed as argument and returns its result, if false, it waits for some time and tries again. After a specified number of attempts, it gives up.

The implementation looks more or less like this.

```js
function attempt<T>(
  f: () => T | Promise<T>,
  p: () => boolean | Promise<boolean>,
  maxAttempts: number,
): Promise<T | null> {
  let attempts = 0

  const poll = (wait: number): Promise<T | null> => new Promise(
    res => Promise.resolve(
      p()
    ).then(
      bool => {
        if (bool) {
          res(f())
        } else if (attempts++ < maxAttempts) {
          setTimeout(
            () => res(poll(wait)),
            wait)
        } else {
          res(null)
        }
      }
    )
  )

  return poll(50)
}
```

If I run the chrome profiler, the very first invocation of this function seems to max out the CPU for the entire duration of the function, with some of the recursive calls taking a lot longer than other ones (see the large stacks compared to the very thin ones).

[image: First run]

Refreshing the page and running it again yields very different results (you almost can't see the function in the profile).

[image: Second run]

Why is this happening? Is it due to some internal V8 optimisation that kicks in after the first time the function is executed?

Comment: Please provide a [complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The maxing out of CPU seems strange. Are you sure it is maxed out, and it's not a misreporting of what's happening in `setTimeout`? (It looks like `setTimeout` itself is busy-waiting, but that would certainly be surprising.)

One thing that's suboptimal is that your function creates up to `maxAttempts` promises, which all wait for one another. Since you are transpiling with TypeScript, there is also the question of what actual JS is being run. On that note, you could use async/await for a much simpler implementation:

```
async function attempt<T>(
  f: () => T | Promise<T>,
  p: () => boolean | Promise<boolean>,
  maxAttempts: number,
): Promise<T | null> {
  for (let i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++) {
    if (await p()) {
      return f();
    }
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 50));
  }
  return null;
}
```

Though I wouldn't expect it to affect what you see for `setTimeout` in the profiler.

Comment: > Are you sure it is maxed out, and it's not a misreporting?

That's part of the question I guess, I don't really know